# Facebook Page URL Showing up in Sitemap (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

Using SEO Framework, Beaver Builder. Sitemap is adding my business facebook page. I want to remove it from the sitemap to get rid of the Google sitemap error.

My sitemap https://whitesandsnaples.com/sitemap.xml

[image]

Comment: Not sure why that tool is including a Facebook URL.  What kind of solution are you hoping for?  Would you be willing to use a different sitemap generator?   Do you want to post-process the sitemap?  Are you hoping for a setting to tweak?

Answer (score 1):

Beaver Builder is not generating this sitemap, [The SEO Framework](https://theseoframework.com/) is.

It sounds like a plugin compatibility issue to me. I once tried using the Slim SEO plugin on a Divi Builder site and it created all kinds of strange issues.

On Beaver Builder's website, they say that it is "Yoast friendly", so I would recommend that you try using that. Yoast is the most popular SEO plugin for WordPress. If switching plugins does not work, customer support will be best suited to help you.

Comment: Thanks Mike. You're right. I'm going to ask SEO Framework first. I used Yoast in past and had some speed issues and others that couldnt be overcome.

Comment: @markcw1 Sounds good.